# Em que parte do Yii2 faço a conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: mysql, yii

Na aplicação Yii2 Framework estou utilizado o template "advanced", estou tendo dificuldade em realizar a conexão.

Em que lugar do framework é feito a conexão com a base de dados do mysql?

Answer (score 0):

O ficheiro que deve de declarar a conecção á base de dados é main-local.php
A print em baixo mostra o sitio exato onde se encontra.

[image: Print da estrutura da Yii2 Advanced]

Dentro do ficheiro deve de encontrar algo deste género.

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_base_de_dados',
        'username' => 'nome_utilizador',
        'password' => 'password_base_de_dados',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
],
```

Onde deve apenas mudar os dados de acesso á base de dados.